# static vs final swift

Tags: swift, static, final

What is the difference between two these words in swift
Static you can not inherit from this class as well as the final. When I should use each of them?

Usually people more concern about static and class word in swift, but the difference is that from static you can not inherent.

Thank you everyone

Comment: 24 million Google search results for the title of this question.  Just saying.  This is the sort of question you could easily find the answer to yourself in Apple's documentation.

Comment: I can see that you not really familiar with this question, that is why you said 24 million, but none of them give the direct answer! Ok, seems I will find out on my own

Comment: I appreciate your attempt at undermining my reply, but it is not that I do not know the difference, it is simply that you didn't take the effort to find out yourself.  You should take the tour before posting any further questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, after a while research I would say that static is used for a property that can be accessed without created a class instance and final is a modifier for a class that from this class nobody can be inherent.

Comment: static also used for methods

Answer (score 1):

- **static**: used for properties or functions of *class* or *struct* and can be accessed  by class/struct level. With static keyword, we cannot override.
- **final**: used for *class* and *class members* (properties or functions). With final keyword, we cannot override.

Note: static is same with "final class" for class members

Answer (score 1):

Common thing between Static and Class is, that they both attaches variables to the Class itself and not to the instance of class.

Where they differ is, you CAN OVERRIDE class properties whereas in case of static you CAN NOT OVERRIDE it in subclass.

Hope this this helps.